# how can an email address is set in BatchableContext in salesforce

Tags: apex, batch, schedulebatch, scheduled-job

I have a batch process scheduled to parse a xml file coming in to Salesforce. This was created by a developer who has left the organization. I wish to deactivate his licence, but that might affect the job scheduled since his name appears in created by column. How can I change the creator of the job. I think the creator of the job gets picked up in a line like below:

```
 AsyncApexJob a = [SELECT Id, Status, NumberOfErrors, JobItemsProcessed,
 TotalJobItems, CreatedBy.Email  FROM AsyncApexJob WHERE Id = :BC.getJobId()];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to make changes once a job is submitted because AsyncApexJob supported calls are only

describeSObjects(), query(), retrieve()

it means you can't make any update into that.

an idea is posted for the same : https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000H11Q

if you want to reschedule you can follow below methods.

1. Select **Apex Class-> schedule apex**
   [image]

[image]

1. You can use System.schedule method to schedule via apex.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_scheduler.htm

Comment: Thanks, How to find out where a scheduled job is created in my apex code. I would like to resubmit the scheduled job and delete the job created by the user who has left the organization

Comment: Got to setup->jobs->Schedule Jobs you will see all the schedule job

Comment: I do not see any option like create or new in this link. Is there a chance that Apex job is created through some apex class?

Comment: Please check updated answer